# Problema al refrescar pagina utilizando Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Mi aplicación en vuejs funciona correctamente en localhost. El problema es cuando lo subi a mi hosting.

Al intentar ingresar a mi raiz todo funciona perfecto, incluso cuando me muevo por medio de `router-link` pero el problema comienza cuando refresco mi pagina en una ruta `https://...com/login` me arroja un error **500**

mi Router lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [ ...
```

Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto, "Solo cuando refresco mi pagina".

> **Problematica**

Quitando:

```
mode: 'history',
```

funciona correctamente, es un buen punto por donde empezar ya que no veo mayor caso el porque este ocacionando este problema, sin embargo... no creo que sea correcto no utilizarlo.

Comment: Si utilizas IIS, revisa este link, creo que es el mismo problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778566/how-to-config-vue-2-application-on-iis-server/45786177

Comment: Puede ser que no estes manejandolo correctamente desde el backend? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277747/refresing-a-vue-app-gives-cannot-get-path

Comment: Revisa la configuración de tu servidor web ahí esta el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder utilizar correctamente el 'history' mode, necesitas activar el 'mod_rewrite' en tu servidor web y añadir un archivo '.htaccess' en la raíz del proyecto que contenga:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Ya depende del tipo de servidor que tengas, si es Apache o NGINX, debes configurarlo de una manera u otra.